# Show element onclick and hide all the others in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a div (a bio description) to open onclick of an image, the code works great except it shows the bio but when I click on other image it's not closing the other bios. How can I make it work so that every time I click on a different image, it shows only the bio related? I want to use only JavaScript.

```
const teamMember = document.getElementsByClassName("team-member");
const teamMemberInfo = document.getElementsByClassName("team-member-info");
for (let i = 0; i < teamMember.length; i++) {
teamMember[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  
  if (teamMemberInfo[i].style.display === "block") {
    teamMemberInfo[i].style.display = "none";
   
  } else {
    teamMemberInfo[i].style.display = "block";
  }
  
});
}
```

CSS code:

```
.team-member-info {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML code: the HTML is part of a php code used in wordpress so I just wrote down the general idea.

```
<div class="team-member">
<img src="someImg.jpg">
</div>

<div class="team-member">
<img src="someOtherImg.jpg">
</div>

<div class="team-member-info">
<div>Some text</div>
</div>

<div class="team-member-info">
<div>Some other text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you clarify what isn't working? are you seeing any errors?

Comment: no errors, what is not working is that when clicked on one team member, only clicking on it again will hide the team member info (bio), I want it to hide also when I click on other team member. in general- I want to show a team member info's one at a time, not all the ones that were clicked. I hope it's a bit more clear

Comment: Please, make a snippet with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you're toggling the visibiliy of your `team-member-info` elements based on their visibility property. This will make a single one visible by clicking on it's related `team-member` element - and invisible if it's clicked again.

What you can do is upon clicking make **all** `team-member-info` elements invisible first and subsequently just one element visible.

Here's an example:

```js
const teamMember = document.getElementsByClassName("team-member");
const teamMemberInfo = document.getElementsByClassName("team-member-info");
for (let i = 0; i < teamMember.length; i++) {
  teamMember[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    for (let a = 0; a < teamMemberInfo.length; a++) {
      teamMemberInfo[a].style.display = "none";
    }
    teamMemberInfo[i].style.display = "block";

  });
}
```

```css
.team-member-info {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="team-member-info">
  <div>Some text</div>
</div>

<div class="team-member-info">
  <div>Some other text</div>
</div>
<div class="team-member">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300">
</div>

<div class="team-member">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/27/200/300">
</div>
```

Just as a side note: using the for-loop to add the click element listeners - and it's associated info boxes - isn't very elegant as the order of the elements connects the clickable elements to the info boxes. I'd recommend either giving all elements an unique id or using the [data property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

## Edit

If you still want to be able to hide an element's 'info box' by clicking it again, you have to check it's current visibility inside the for-loop which hides all info boxes.

Here's the updated example:

```js
const teamMember = document.getElementsByClassName("team-member");
const teamMemberInfo = document.getElementsByClassName("team-member-info");
for (let i = 0; i < teamMember.length; i++) {
  teamMember[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    for (let a = 0; a < teamMemberInfo.length; a++) {
      if (teamMemberInfo[a] != teamMemberInfo[i]) {
        teamMemberInfo[a].style.display = "none";
      } else {
        if (teamMemberInfo[i].style.display == "none" || teamMemberInfo[i].style.display == "") {
          teamMemberInfo[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
          teamMemberInfo[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.team-member-info {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="team-member-info">
  <div>Some text</div>
</div>

<div class="team-member-info">
  <div>Some other text</div>
</div>
<div class="team-member">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300">
</div>

<div class="team-member">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/27/200/300">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! that really answers the question, just now the same image that I clicked on to show the info, won't hide it on clicking this image again. Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: No problem Miri - glad I could help! I've just updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You iterate over team members to add event listeners, but your event listeners need a separate function to iterate over the team members.

Perhaps something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/6h3c09by/1/

```
const teamMember = document.getElementsByClassName("team-member");
const teamMemberInfo = document.getElementsByClassName("team-member-info");

const processTeamMembers = (j) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < teamMember.length; i++) {
    if (i !== j) {
      teamMemberInfo[i].style.display = "none";
    } else {
      teamMemberInfo[i].style.display = "block";
    }
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < teamMember.length; i++) {
    teamMember[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        processTeamMembers(i);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add a function

```
function hideAllOthers(currentElem) {
   for (let i = 0; i < teamMember.length; i++) {
      if (teamMember[i] == currentElem) continue;
   
      teamMemberInfo[i].style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

and add it to the beggining of the eventListener

```
    teamMember[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    **hideAllOthers(teamMember[i]);**

  if (teamMemberInfo[i].style.display === "block") {
    teamMemberInfo[i].style.display = "none";
   
  } else {
    teamMemberInfo[i].style.display = "block";
  }
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I think you might want to consider some kind of key or data attr and id to tie the images to the content sections so you are sure you are binding the right image to the right content. That would also make the javascript easier and more clear.

However, that answers a question you didn't ask. To answer the question using the code as you gave, make sure that the order of the images and the order of the descriptions are in the same order. If you don't this approach falls appart pretty fast because it needs the indexs of the nodes to be the same.

As you have it now change your js to this:

```js
const teamMember = document.getElementsByClassName("team-member");
const teamMemberInfo = document.getElementsByClassName("team-member-info");
for (let i = 0; i < teamMember.length; i++) {
teamMember[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  for(let tmi = 0; tmi < teamMemberInfo.length; tmi++){
            teamMemberInfo[tmi].style.display = "none"; // depending on what you're doing
        }
    teamMemberInfo[i].style.display = "block";
});
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! there's only a problem of hiding the current displayed team member info by clicking on the image it's related to. Now it shows one of the infos but without the ability of hiding it completely. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Sorry, just getting back. Checkout obscure's answer update. Seems to do just what you asked for. :)